# How to subset (or filter?) taxa in a phyloseq object, within a grouping?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, phyloseq

I am attempting to subset (or filter?) taxa that have relative abundance >= 35%,and belong in >= 70% of samples within a grouping (in my case it is the number of 'clusters' in my data).

Is there a simple line of code on how to do this? I have started to do this with this line of code

```
subset <- filter_taxa(phyloseq_object, function (x) sum (x) > 0.35, TRUE)
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to apply this filtration step to see if these taxa belong within >= 70% of my samples. Maybe using something like this within a grouping?

```
prevalenceThreshold = 0.70 * nsamples(phyloseq_object)
```

I have a column in my sample_data file, named 'cluster' with 8 defined clusters.
Maybe I am overthinking it, but I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Edit** I am performing this in R version 4.1.2 with MacOS Monterey 12.2.1. Here is a subset of my data:

[Here is a subset of my data. I could not fit the column 'cluster' within the image. Each sample belongs to 1 cluster.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ndXS.png)

Comment: Hi! I think you will have a great answer if you share your data. You can use `dput(head(data))` to select a subset of your df. I suggest you take a look at this post about making reproducible examples in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you! I added an image of the subset of my df. I hope this helps. Do you have any ideas on how I could subset these taxa?

Comment: When @Jose wrote to include data, there was a function and link provided, but you didn't use them. If your data is proprietary, then use a built-in dataset in your question, so it's repeatable (along with including whatever your objective is). However,  you may be able to use `get_top_taxa` and use `.7 * nrow(object@table)` to get 70% of the data. That function is in a non-Cran library. Use `devtools::install_github("gmteunisse/Fantaxtic")` and `library(fantaxtic)`. It depends on what you want to do with the subset, though.

Comment: I attempted to include a subset of my df, but the print out was quite messy so I thought the screenshot was much more sufficient. I used head(sample_data(phyloseq_object)) to include the table. Is there a better way to present this? Thank you for the function. My objective is I am trying to determine if the subset of data (the top 35% of taxa) are present in at least 70% of my samples (indicated with the prevalenceThreshold). Would this require a TRUE/FALSE statement? This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.